# Displaying contents of a tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I have been trying to figure out how to accomplish what I need done which I can show [here](http://www.keepandshare.com/userpics/d/a/v/e/8528sky/2015-01/sb/screenshot_1_21_2015_11_23_29_pm-3914021.jpg?ts=1421913116)
.  I had asked this question in [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029820/jquery-modification-needed/28029906#28029906) which I got a good answer but I don't know how to implement it i wordpress.  I placed the jQuery as needed for `.siblings()` as suggested in function.php like this:

```
wp_register_script('flatmarket-jquery2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery2.js', array(), '2.1.0', true);
```

I have not been able to get it to work on wordpress.

I am using Page composer which it provides you tools to place JS and HTML in the places you need. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have been answered in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029820/jquery-modification-needed/28029906#28029906) in the following way:

```
 <div id="tab-one" style="display: none">Tab1 info 1 content</div>
 <div id="tab-two" style="display: none">Tab1 info 2 content</div>
 <div id="tab-three" style="display: none">Tab1 info 3 content</div>

 <ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li class="one">Tab1 info 1</li>
  <li class="two">Tab1 info 2</li>
  <li class="three">Tab1 info 3</li>  
</ul>
```

You should run your query in while loop to get the result. define a $i = 1 before loop and increment it before closing while loop like $i++; Now change your html like this:

```
<div id="tab-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display: none">code to get tab content</div>
<ul>
    <li class="<?php echo $i; ?>">Code to get tab title</li>
</ul>
```

If you have any confusion. write in comment box.

Comment: That is what I had originally, but the content of other tabs would not clear after clicking on another tab.  That's why that person suggested  .sibling function.  Anyway, I want to use his jquery but I don't know where to place the jquery in wordpress and I show where I placed it above but it does not work.

Comment: Arshad, I'm a newbie.  Can you please explain a bit more?  where you say "code to get tab content"  what would that be?

Comment: Put it as follows: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery2.js"></script>

Comment: placing this in function.php created errors so I placed what I had in header.php and it worked.  Now my problem is when tab1 content is displayed and if I click on Tab2, its content display below the tab1's.  So, the contents of previous tab don't go away.  Any ideas to get this worked out? Thanks.

Comment: You are loading two jquery library in the site. Press clt+u in website and press ctl+F and search "jquery". Or give me your site url.

Comment: There are more than one jquery file.  I think for the purpose of what I need to accomplish, perhaps I should only make-available the function that I need in that particular jquery (I think it's "siblings()"  ) and remove the rest so it wont create a conflict. What do you think?